# What is the exact meaning of an assignment operator?

Tags: c, lvalue, rvalue

I assume when we declare `int a ; a=10;`, then the compiler takes r-value & put it in it's l-value. At that time the l-value always treated as a address in the memory location i.e. a or any other variable in assignment operation at the left hand side treated as `(&variable)`. So we are able to catch its address to put the r-value in it.

Is my assumption is right or wrong?If wrong, then what is basic idea behind it?

Comment: "Container class" is a C++-specific term.

Comment: I believe you are *effectively* correct, remember the compiler converts that into native machine code I would guess it's going to be a [`MOV`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOV_%28x86_instruction%29) instruction. It depends on what you mean by "container class", I assume you mean type.

Answer (score 2):

You're making it more complicated than it needs to be.  The [language definition](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) simply states:

> An assignment operator stores a value in the object designated by the left operand.

(6.5.16, para 3).

The only general constraint is that the left operand be a modifiable lvalue.  An lvalue can correspond to a *register* (which has no address) or an addressable memory location.  Exactly how it happens is an implementation detail.

Comment: Or, the lvalue might have no physical representation in the final program at all: the compiler might be able to short-cut all uses of that variable and assign the value directly to it's final destination.

Answer (score 1):

An assignment operator has two operands. The left operand must be a "modifiable lvalue".

An "lvalue" is, roughly, an expression that designates an object.

(An "rvalue", as the C standard uses the term, is simply the value that results from evaluating an expression. The C standard defines the term, but rarely uses it. The usage is a bit inconsistent: an "lvalue" is an expression, but an "rvalue" is a value.)

The right operand is *evaluated* to yield a value. That value is then converted, if necessary, to the type of the left operand, and the result is *stored* in the object designated by the left operand.

Addresses are not required. For example, a variable defined with `register` has no address, but it can still be the target of an assignment.

If you want the gory details, see section 6.5.16 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (the link is to `n1570.pdf`, the most recent draft, a 1.7-megabyte PDF).

Comment: in simple words the modifiable l-value is get replaced by new r-value is it ?

Comment: @SumeetBajiraoGaikwad: Not really. An *lvalue* is not an object; it's an expression that designates an object. An *rvalue* (a term the C standard defines but rarely uses) is just the value of an expression. The value that results from evaluating the RHS is stored in the object designated by the LHS, replacing whatever value (if any) it previously had.

Comment: @SumeetBajiraoGaikwad - No.  The value *in* the lvalue is replaced.

Comment: @HotLicks: No. An lvalue is a kind of expression. There is no "value in the lvalue". There is a value *of* the object *designated by* the lvalue.

Comment: @KeithThompson - Yeah, you can dance around the terminology a lot.  The more precisely you try to define it, the harder it gets to understand.  (But, yes, "designated" is probably the better term.)

Comment: @HotLicks: I disagree. These words have very specific meanings, and using them imprecisely IMHO is what leads to confusion.

Comment: @KeithThompson - The point is that the "very specific meanings" are understood by very few people, and to most of the rest they appear to be gibberish.

Comment: @HotLicks: Which is why I explained their meanings. I suggest using words like "lvalue" and "rvalue" either correctly or not at all.

Comment: Where did you explain their meanings??

Comment: @HotLicks: In my answer. (I added an explanation of "rvalue" just a moment ago, copied from a comment I posted about an hour ago.)

Comment: If you say so.  I don't see it.

Comment: @HotLicks: Second and third paragraphs. What are you missing?

Comment: "An expression that designates an object" is meaningless to anyone but perhaps a C standards lawyer.  But I'm done here.

Comment: @HotLicks: If you don't understand it, feel free to ask for clarification. If you think others won't understand it, *they* should feel free to ask for clarification. I welcome *constructive* criticism.

Answer (score 0):

The terms "lvalue" and "rvalue" come from being on the left and right of the `=` symbol and hence are self-reflexive definitions.  (Ie, not real helpful.)

But the important point is that an rvalue must be able to produce a value (ie, finite pattern of bits), while an lvalue must be capable of being having assigned to it a similar value.

As such, an lvalue must ultimately represent a storage address or register or I/O port or something else (is there anything else?) that can be "written to".  But this does not mean that the lvalue *contains* an address -- it merely represents the addressable entity in the compiler, and will be translated to "real" addressing info in the generated assembly.  Ie, it's simply a name for something.

An rvalue, on the other hand, need not represent a "real thing", but can be a literal or some expression or call or whatever, so long as it produces a "value" when asked.